# php SSL client certificate authentication

Tags: php, ssl

I already heard of `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN` attribute of `$_SERVER` variable ( yet I am failing in configure apache to get this variable but this is another topic).
And I wonder if I am able to get `*.crt` file of those values. Does anyone have done this? Such operation is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']`

For this attribute to be filled, you need to add `SSLOptions +ExportCertData` to your apache config

Never tried though, I use 'SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_*' attributes so the complete certificate will not be send with every request from apache to php : explained [here](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm)